# Faster chkdsk alternative

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, chkdsk, hard-drive-recovery

I think at some point my laptop's (secondary) internal hard drive was disconnected, and it seems like there are a lot of bad sectors (though I don't think anything is inherently wrong with the drive?).

Anyway, I'm running chkdsk, but after a little while it just says "File record segment XXXXXX is unreadable." over and over. The ETA is 999 hours. Is there a faster way to put the drive in a usable state? I would prefer to do this without nuking the drive, since my backup is about a month old (though I think I've synced everything important to Dropbox anyway).

Answer (score -1):

At least you have backups of that drive - good work! It's obvious from all the error messages that the file system on that drive is ruined, and a reformat is called for. If you can't do a fresh format, then Disk Part might be a last ditch option.